# Why doesn't my file upload function work properly? PHP

Tags: php, upload

Hi I have a file upload function. Controls **file size** and **file type**. If the file is in PDF format and is smaller than 10MB, everything works as it should.

If the file is not PDF, it should show me the message: "ERROR: You can just upload PDF files." but no message.

If the file size is larger than 10MB, it should show me the message: "ERROR: Max file size 10MB." but no message.

**If the file is PDF but larger than 10MB, it shows me: "ERROR: All fields must be filled."**

What is wrong with my code?

Function :

```
<?php

function file_create($file) {

    if(isset($file)){

        $errors     = array();
        $target_dir = "../files/";
        $file_name  = uniqid();
        $file_size  = $file['size'];
        $file_tmp   = $file['tmp_name'];
        $file_type  = $file['type'];
        $file_ext   = strtolower(end(explode('.',$file['name'])));

        if($file_type != "application/pdf") {

            $error = "ERROR : You can upload just PDF files.";
            array_push($errors, $error);

        }

        if($file_size > 1024*1024*10) {

            $error = "ERROR : Max file size 10MB.";
            array_push($errors, $error);

        }

        if(empty($errors) == true) {

            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$target_dir.$file_name.".".$file_ext);

            $errors['status'] = true;
            $errors['patch'] = substr($target_dir.$file_name.".".$file_ext, 3);

        } else {

            $errors['status'] = false;

        }

        return $errors;

    }

}

?>
```

Another File :

```
<?php

$errors = array();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $notice_title       = secured_post("notice-title");
    $notice_content     = secured_post("notice-content");

    // if there is empty field in form.
    if (multi_empty($notice_title, $notice_content)) {

        // if a file submitted.
        if (isset($_FILES['notice-file'])) {

            $notice_file = $_FILES['notice-file'];

            // upload the file.
            $upload = file_create($notice_file);

            if ($upload['status'] == false) {

                $size = count($upload);

                for ($i=0; $i < $size; $i++) { 

                    array_push($errors, $upload[$i]);

                }

            }

            notice_create($conn, $notice_title, $notice_content, $upload['patch']);

        } else {

            notice_create($conn, $notice_title, $notice_content);

        }

    } else {

        $error = "ERROR : All fields must be filled.";
        array_push($errors, $error);

    }

}

if ($errors) {

    foreach ($errors as $error) {

        echo "<div class='error'>".$error."</div></br>";

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Can you post your code without so many blank lines, so we don't have to scroll to see it all?

Comment: What does `secured_post()` do?

Comment: What is your PHP `upload_max_filesize` setting?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem. If your file is larger than 10MB then it can take some time to upload the file so you have to check if the `$_FILES` array is empty or not.

Try this:

```
<?php
$errors = array();
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_FILES)) {  //I've made changes to this line
    $notice_title       = secured_post("notice-title");
    $notice_content     = secured_post("notice-content");
    // if there is empty field in form.
    if (multi_empty($notice_title, $notice_content)) {
        // if a file submitted.
        if (isset($_FILES['notice-file'])) {
            $notice_file = $_FILES['notice-file'];
            // upload the file.
            $upload = file_create($notice_file);
            if ($upload['status'] == false) {
                $size = count($upload);
                for ($i=0; $i < $size; $i++) { 
                    array_push($errors, $upload[$i]);
                }
            }
            notice_create($conn, $notice_title, $notice_content, $upload['patch']);
        } else {
            notice_create($conn, $notice_title, $notice_content);
        }
    } else {
        $error = "ERROR : All fields must be filled.";
        array_push($errors, $error);
    }
}
if ($errors) {
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo "<div class='error'>".$error."</div></br>";
    }
}
?>
```

And:

```
<?php
function file_create($file) {
    if(!empty($file)){  //I've made changes to this line
        $errors     = array();
        $target_dir = "../files/";
        $file_name  = uniqid();
        $file_size  = $file['size'];
        $file_tmp   = $file['tmp_name'];
        $file_type  = $file['type'];
        $file_ext   = strtolower(end(explode('.',$file['name'])));
        if($file_type != "application/pdf" || $file_ext != ".pdf") {  //I've made changes to this line
            $error = "ERROR : You can upload just PDF files.";
            array_push($errors, $error);
        }
        if($file_size > (1024*1024*10)) {
            $error = "ERROR : Max file size 10MB.";
            array_push($errors, $error);
        }
        if(empty($errors) == true) {
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$target_dir.$file_name.".".$file_ext);
            $errors['status'] = true;
            $errors['patch'] = substr($target_dir.$file_name.".".$file_ext, 3);
        } else {
            $errors['status'] = false;
        }
        return $errors;
    }
}
?>
```

**Note:** The `$_FILES` array can be set and empty at the same time so `isset()` can't help you here.

Comment: The script doesn't run until the upload is complete. The time it takes shouldn't matter.

Comment: Well I've encountered a lot of cases where you submit but the file isn't uploaded yet and it causes the exact same issue.

Comment: The file is part of the form. Everything is submitted together, and the PHP script runs after it's all received.

Comment: Are you saying that it will run the script repeatedly, first with empty `$_FILES` and then again with `$_FILES` filled in?

Comment: So you just ignore the first run, and wait for it to call it again with everything?

Comment: No it will run the script without the file, and therefore send an error.

Comment: So how do you get the uploaded file when that happens?

Comment: I usually set the upload limit at 2MB  because I never dealt with files larger than that. But it all depends on how he's sending the data. If he's using ajax then it might send the data before the file is uploaded.

Comment: If he's sending it with a separate AJAX request, the file size wouldn't affect whether it works.

Comment: If the file doesn't get send then the `$_FILES` array will be empty so he can't get the file size or any data about the file